# Problem with Data Type in my Python/Django Code

Tags: python, django

***I have update my code example as it had some minor inconsistencies with my real code***

I'm running into a noob issue with my code.
It's a simple multiplier function working like as:

1/ A Model 
1.a/ with 2 fields : name as CharField and price as Decimalfield
1.b/ with a method Multiplier that is basically newprice = self.price * arg

2/ A form
to capture an input (the value to multiply self.price with)

3/ A view to pass the template with the form and the context

I keep running into can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'NoneType' or TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) errors.
I tried updating the code to change the type of my object, or model fiels, etc but cannot find a working solution...

btw : if the model method has its argument replaced by a constant, everything is working as it should

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def multi(self, n):
        np = self.price * n
        return np
```

Form

```
class Input(forms.Form):
    data = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

View

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product
from .forms import Input
from decimal import Decimal

def index(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()
    value = 1
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Input(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            value = request.POST.get('data')
                                   ##what shoud I do here
            Product.multi(value) ##Is this correct ??


    else:
        form = Input(request.POST or None)

    return render(request , 'multi/index.html', {'form' : form, 'list' : list, 'value' : value} )
```

Template

```
        {% block content %}
    <h2>New price</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="price-form" name="data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
<br>
{{ value }}
<br><br>

        {% for list in list %}
        <div>
     {{ list.name }} {{ list.price }} {{ list.multi }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `p = Product()` This creates a new Product model instance with no name or price information.  It makes no sense to call `p.multi()` on such an instance, as `self.price` is None.

Comment: `{% for list in list %}` Also, it's a really bad idea to name your loop variable the same name as the thing you're looping over.

Comment: You've also no field named `sku` within `Product` but your returning this in `def __str__(self):`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The sku variable is actually the one in my code by I changed it to name for clarity purpose on my question.
About the loop variable, I will change it in the future,

So far I'm trying to find what is causing the problem with the simple multiplication method..Is it the Data Type , the instancing itself,...I ve tried so many combination resluting in so many error type I cant tell anymore

Comment: What is the purpose of the form?  What is the intent of the `value` form field?  Is the user supposed to be entering a price multiplier for a product?  For _all_ products?

Comment: @JohnGordon : yes, the input form objective is to ,get a numerical value from the  user. This value is then passed as an argument (n) to the method called multi.
It return a new value that is (self.price * arg) . This new self.multi value is displayed on the template. In the end all products price are multipled by the same number. that is what I want in the end


but maybe I'm all wrong here...because I can display a self.multi value without passing/instancing any method by removing the n-argument and adding a numerical constant directly in the method...